# Shopping cart in PHP : Sessions or Database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, session

I am currently developing a simple shopping cart using PHP & HTML. 
I've been having troubles with using the SESSIONS in Php like:

- Sessions not continuing when I switch pages even though I called the `session_start()` at the top of  every page.

Is it a better approach to use sessions in keeping track of a clients cart?

My requirements are as follows:

1. Keep track of users cart when user is switching pages.
2. Save users cart to database when the user proceeds to check out.
3. Clear users cart(session) when it has been idle for 30 minutes.

Comment: Each has its own advantages and disadvantages. Some sites use both. The question for you is that beyond the "shopping cart", what are you going to do with the data?

Comment: Data after the shopping cart will be inserted in a table. @MichaelT

Comment: What if the user abandons the cart? How long are you going to allow them to come back to the same cart? Do you allow switching of cart to and from a wishlist? Is there more data about how long between actions that you want to persist? If you are persisting it in a database, how often do you clean it out? I will stress that these are questions about the business requirements that you have. If you *don't* have them, you need to find out what they are. If you do have them, you need to include it in the question. If you are having trouble with the code, that is off topic here.

Comment: I edited the question sir @MichaelT.

Comment: Even if you store the cart in the database, how are you going to reliably identify the user on each page load (and link them to their cart) if your session data is unreliable - you need to find out why you sessions are breaking.

Comment: Okay, lets say i get to fixed the reason for session breaking. You're saying the best way to do this is by using SESSIONS?  @HorusKol

Comment: no - i'm saying you need to find out why sessions are breaking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either way you will want to use sessions for persisting data through the customer experience since you're ultimately working across a stateless protocol. If I have to implement a database then I go ahead and move the sessions to the database (the client may still need a cookie depending on how you decide to go about that.) As for the cart, as soon as I had to use a database, I tended to move it to the database as well. When I'd use a framework like CodeIgniter then I'd let it make the call unless I had a compelling reason to do otherwise. Since to meet #2 you'll have to design the db to store a cart at checkout, then you may as well store it in the db across the user's experience. I'd take a look at this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569568/shopping-cart-persistence-session-or-browser-cookie

Comment: Thank you for this one, this is just the justification I need for using SESSIONS.

Answer (score -5):

I don't know what your code looks like, here is mine and it works：

```
//page1.php
<?php 
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['name'] = 'Bee';
?>
<a href="page2.php">next</a>

//page2.php
<?php 
  session_start();
  echo 'Hello, '. $_SESSION['name'];
?>
```

And I would rather use sessions, cause I think it's more simple to process the business tasks